# How to map two data frames in python?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a data frame which can has n number of P_Id values for each Id.

```
X = Id    P_Id     Value
    1      a_1      56
    1      a_2      76
    2      a_1      67
    2      a_2      78
    2      a_3      98
```

I have another data frame

```
Y =  Id  Name 
     1    Erwin
     2    Joseph
     3     Nik
```

I want the out put data frame to be

```
Output =  Id  a_1  a_2   a_3  Name
          1    56   76   nan   Erwin
          2    67   78   98    Joseph
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inner `merge` x, and y, then `pivot` this merged dataframe,then merge back to the second dataframe, finally, you can reset the index, .

```py
x.merge(y, how='inner', on='Id').pivot(columns='P_Id', values='Value').merge(y, on='Id').reset_index()
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
   Id   a_1   a_2   a_3    Name
0   1  56.0  76.0   NaN   Erwin
1   2  67.0  78.0  98.0  Joseph
```

Comment: Error - No common columns to perform merge on. Merge options: left_on=None, right_on=None, left_index=False, right_index=False

Comment: That's because `Id` is index in both the dataframes, if that's the case, either reset the indices of both the dataframes, or pass `on='Id'` to the merge function.